# If you explicitly throw an unchecked exception in your code, isn't it now a checked exception - because the compiler can now check if it's handled?

Tags: java

In Cay Horstmann's Java 9 book, it says

```
Integer.parseInt(String str);
```

"it throws an unchecked NumberFormatException".

NumberFormatException inherits from RuntimeException.
When I look at the Java 11 docs, it is declared in the signature.
So calling methods must handle it at some point.

```
public static int parseInt(String s) throws NumberFormatException
```

isn't it now a checked exception - because the compiler can check its usage?

**Update**: Does the compiler check if the `NumberFormatException` is handled by the caller? I don't see any benefit that calling methods (or even those far from the calling method) are never required by the compiler to catch the checked exception.

Comment: No. The `throws` clause is entirely for the benefit of programmers reading the documentation.

Comment: It is a *declared* exception - that doesn't make it a *checked* exception. The compiler doesn't *check* that `NumberFormatException` is only thrown from this method or other methods declaring it.

Comment: @kaya3 "The compiler doesn't check that NumberFormatException is only thrown from this method or other methods declaring it." huh? I don't understand. In order to compile the code, the compiler must check that the exception is thrown.

Comment: No, it is perfectly allowed to declare an exception that is not actually thrown, like `void foo() throws Exception { /* do nothing */ }`. A "checked exception" doesn't mean the compiler checks that each method *can* throw the exceptions it declares, it means the compiler checks that that type of exception *can only* be thrown by methods that declare it.

Comment: @kaya3 Does the compiler check if the NumberFormatException is handled by the caller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could have been, but the language simply isn't designed that way.

A few things just are.

- All source files secretly have `import java.lang.*;` in them. Whether you write it or not. The compiler acts exactly as if it was there.
- All methods and constructors act as if they have `throws RuntimeException, Error;` on them. You can't make a method not have this. Whatever you decree is just added to that pile. Therefore, any method that invokes a method that is known to throw `NumberFormatException` doesn't need to handle it, as it has declared that it throws it onwards (because **all** methods are defined as `throws RuntimeException` even if you didn't write that, and NFEx is a subtype of RuntimeException.

An intriguing alternate take on exceptions could be that anything that is declared explicitly is therefore checked, and anything that is not is therefore unchecked, and java grows a new `throw` instruction that doesn't require that you also declare that type in your `throws` block.

But, java doesn't work that way, and as far as I know, no language out there does.

NB: So why are some methods declared explicitly as throwing some unchecked exception type, why do some source files include `import java.lang.*;`? Because the author of said file thinks it helps readability. That import statement is hard to rhyme and indeed you rarely see that. But explicitly declaring that you throw an unchecked type is somewhat common. The reason they do this is *solely* for readability. It does nothing. It's a comment that isn't in `/* */`. Comments do absolutely nothing either and yet people do write that.

Comment: But why can't the compiler check if it is handled since it is now declared?

Comment: @likejudo Reread the answer. It IS checking if it is handled, and the answer is always yes: It is handled because the method has `throws RuntimeException`. Even if you see some sort of plan to change how java works at a fundamental level, it would mean a ton of existing code now no longer works, and java doesn't do that sort of thing.

Comment: You said, "It IS checking if it is handled, and the answer is always yes:". This contradicts the answer from @Stephen C. Both of you have high scores - but only one answer is correct. Which one?

Comment: Both are correct - There is the concept of 'checking' if an exception must be handled or not, which applies to all throwables, whether they extend RuntimeException/Error or not, but all methods/constructors implicitly always throw RuntimeException/Error, so the checking part is trivial. Separately, RuntimeException, Error, and subtypes thereof tend to be called 'unchecked exceptions'. They are still checked, but the check trivially always passes, so, we're mincing words here.

Comment: Agreed.  The JLS is completely clear on this.  @likejudo - you are nitpicking about the meaning of the informal term "handled" that isn't even used in the JLS in this context.  If you really want to continue arguing about this, please provide the precise JLS quotations to justify your assertions.

Comment: By 'handled', I meant having a `try`, `catch` somewhere in the call sequence. Does the compiler check if a try-catch is in the call sequence of the code, when it sees a `throws NumberFormatException` in a method signature?

Comment: @likejudo that definition of 'handled' just isn't how java works. 'handled' is defined by: _Is in a `try` block that has a `catch` of that type OR is in a method that is declared to throw it_. The compiler checks that one of those 2 is present, even for `NumberFormatException`, and finds that: Yes, it is present (specifically, the method declared `throws X`, where X is `NumberFormatException` or some supertype thereof.

Comment: @rzwitserloot so even for a checked exception, a method just has to declare that it throws the checked exception, and the compiler will never check that it was caught anywhere? I don't see any benefit that calling methods are never required to catch the checked exception (even if far from the throwing method).

Comment: _a method just has to declare that it throws the checked exception, and the compiler will never check that it was caught anywhere?_ __Correct__. Of course, that method is useless unless somebody calls it, and then __they__ have to catch it, or declare it in its throws clause. And that process doesn't end until you get to your 'entry point', such as `public static void main`. Which _can_ be declared with `throws Exception`, if you want (and you usually should - main can throw whatever it likes. It's library methods that need to manage their exceptions).

Comment: NB: If you don't see the point, experiment some or think some more. It's fairly obvious: All checked exceptions need to be caught somewhere, you're just allowed (via `throws` clauses) to delay the point at which you deal with it, as far as you wanna take that, but you have to declare this explicitly, and that becomes part of your API.

Comment: @rzwitserloot thanks for patiently explaining. I experimented and now understand it better.

Answer (score 4):

> ... isn't it now a checked exception - because the compiler can check its usage?

No.

JLS [11.1.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.1.1) says this:

> The *checked exception* classes are all exception classes other than the *unchecked exception* classes. That is, the *checked exception* classes are `Throwable` and all its subclasses other than `RuntimeException` and its subclasses and `Error` and its subclasses.

That is the definition.

You can declare *any* exception in a `throws` clause, but only checked exceptions are checked by the compiler to ensure that they are handled or declared in the calling method.

---

> So calling methods must handle it at some point.

Incorrect.

A `throws` for an **unchecked** exception doesn't alter the way the compiler handles the code, and doesn't alter any runtime behavior either.  The `throws` does not make an exception checked.  It does not force the calling method to handle the exception.

The (ostensible) reason for declaring an unchecked exception in a `throws` clause is to *document* the fact that the exception may be thrown by the method.  This will translate into text in the method's javadocs that the programmer can (should) read to understand the method and how to use it.

---

In your example, `NumberFormatException` is a subclass of `RuntimeException`, so it is NOT a checked exception; see the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html).  However, a programmer still needs to know that `parseInt` can throw an (unchecked!) `NumberFormatException`, so they have included `throws NumberFormatException` in the `parseInt` declaration anyway.

---

OK, so what would be the effect of the semantic you are suggesting?

What it would mean is that exceptions are checked or unchecked based on what the method's `throws` clause.  So one method might declare that `NumberFormatException` is checked, and another that it is not checked.

I think that the compiler could cope with this.  But I'm not sure that a typical programmer could.  For example, it makes the decision of what to put in a method's `throws` clause a lot harder.

The second thing is that this would allow programmers to effectively ignore checked exceptions by not using any `throws` clauses.  But the original Java rationale was that it was better to force the programmer to deal with the exceptions ... because that leads to code that is more robust.  Java checked exceptions (as currently specified) eliminate a significant class of programmer errors at compile time.

To avoid that second problem you would need some extra syntax that allowed the programmer to explicitly mark an exception as unchecked.  For example

```
public void method1() throws AnException, AnotherException { 
     ...
}

public void method2() {
    try {
        method1();
    } catch (AnException e) {
    } unchecked AnotherException
}
```

whether the `unchecked` clause means that `AnotherException` no longer is treated as checked ... and doesn't *need* to be declared by `method2`.

(But I can imagine many programmers abusing an `unchecked` construct if it was provided by the language.)

Comment: Are you saying that the compiler doesn't check if it is handled (in my example)? I am not suggesting to change the language. It does not make sense to me that the compiler doesn't check if it is handled since it is now declared.

Comment: The compiler doesn't check that `NumberFormatException` is handled because `NumberFormatException` is not a checked exception.  If you look at the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html), you will see that `NumberFormatException` has `RuntimeException` as a superclass.

Comment: You said, "The compiler doesn't check that NumberFormatException is handled". This contradicts the answer below from @rzwitserloot. Who is right?

Comment: I think that maybe he misspoke in his comments.  (He has conflated "declared in the `throws` clause" with handling an exception.)  But it is not relevant, because the JLS doesn't express the rules in those terms anyway.  If you really want to understand this stuff, read the JLS ... and read it very carefully.  Start by reading and understanding **all** of [Chapter 11](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-11.html)

Comment: For the record, the non-normative description of the relationship between the throws clause and exceptions thrown is as follows: *"Essentially, for each checked exception that can result from execution of the body of a method or constructor, a compile-time error occurs unless its exception type or a supertype of its exception type **is mentioned in** a throws clause in the declaration of the method or constructor."*.  It does not use the word "handled".  So nitpicking about what "handled" means is irrelevant.